# Is there a `join` function in Hugo templates?

Tags: templates, hugo, go-templates

There is a `split` function in Hugo templates which takes a string and returns an array, but there does not seem to be an equivelant `join` function.

I would like to create a comma separated list from the `.Keywords` in the front matter which is an array of strings. How can I do this in a Hugo template?

Answer (score 2):

The `delimit` function does this